# Как дать доступ на firebase, Гугл аналитику, Google API Console

Tags: доступ

Как дать доступ на firebase, Гугл аналитику, Google API Console другому человеку, что он там создал  свои проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как известно мне, права о которых говорите Вы можно передать только вместе с паролем к аккаунту разработчика (надеюсь меня поправят, если это не так). А вот добавить Права доступа к Проекту можно. В консоли к **Проекту** перейти в Настройки (иконка-шестеренка в левом верхнем углу) и выбрать пункт "**Права доступа**"-> "**Добавить**".